# shouldStartLoadWithRequest is never called

Tags: ios, methods, protocols, uiwebviewdelegate

I've researched and researched and still don't understand why shouldStartLoadWithRequest is never called. My page loads fine and some of the UIWebview delegate protocol methods are called.  Please find relevant snippets from my code below:

Synthesize my webview in my .m (defined in a header file):

```
@implementation PortViewController

@synthesize WebView = myWebView;
```

I load my webview successfully:

```
    myURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@", defaultWebsite];

    myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: myURLString];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

set my delegate to self

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


[super viewDidLoad];
[myWebView setOpaque:NO];
[myWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

//myWebView.description.

myWebView.delegate = self;
}
```

all of my protocol methods are called EXCEPT shouldStartLoadWithRequest

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)myWebView {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)myWebView {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (BOOL)WebView:(UIWebView *)myWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request          navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

NSLog(@"inside Webview");
if([[request.URL absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"http://www.nzx"]) {
    // do stuff
    NSLog(@"Have caught the prefix");
    return YES;
}

    return NO;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a typo or you actually have implemented incorrect method `WebView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`? The `W` should be small case `webView`.

Answer (score 14):

Try setting the delegate in ViewWillAppear instead of ViewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     myWebView.delegate = self;
}
```

and include the webview delegate in your interface of PortViewController.m file

```
@interface PortViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate>


@end
```

It should work.

Comment: thanks!!

excellent answer. you can simplify it by not needing to set the the interface to PortViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate>

Answer (score 1):

delegate method should be:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

And if you have `UIWebView` in xib, then probably you are trying to load request when `UIWebView` is nil

So make sure your myWebView instance exists.

Comment: It was the wayward lowercase 'w' thanks. I'm off to buy some spectacles.

Comment: that's why "autocompletion" for. From moment you've declared your class supports some protocol < someDelegate >, you are able just typing methods with autocompletion for that delegate