# How can i monitor requests on WKWebview?

Tags: javascript, ios, monitor, wkwebview, nsurlprotocol

**How can i monitor requests on WKWebview?**

I'v tried using  NSURLprotocol (canInitWithRequest) but it won't monitor ajax requests (XHR), only navigation requests(document requests)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Finally I solved it

Since I don't have control over the web view content, I injected to the WKWebview a java script that include a jQuery AJAX request listener.

When the listener catches a request it sends the native app the request body in the method:

```
webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(data);
```

The native app catches the message in a delegate called:

```
(void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message
```

and perform the corresponding actions

here is the relevant code:

ajaxHandler.js  -

```
//Every time an Ajax call is being invoked the listener will recognize it and  will call the native app with the request details

$( document ).ajaxSend(function( event, request, settings )  {
    callNativeApp (settings.data);
});

function callNativeApp (data) {
    try {
        webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(data);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('The native context does not exist yet');
    }
}
```

My ViewController delegate are:

```
@interface BrowserViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler, UIWebViewDelegate>
```

And in my `viewDidLoad()`, I'm creating a WKWebView:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc]init];
[self addUserScriptToUserContentController:configuration.userContentController];
appWebView = [[WKWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:configuration];
appWebView.UIDelegate = self;
appWebView.navigationDelegate = self;
[appWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://#############"]]];
```

Here is the addUserScriptToUserContentController:

```
- (void) addUserScriptToUserContentController:(WKUserContentController *) userContentController{
    NSString *jsHandler = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"ajaxHandler" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    WKUserScript *ajaxHandler = [[WKUserScript alloc]initWithSource:jsHandler injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:NO];
    [userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"callbackHandler"];
    [userContentController addUserScript:ajaxHandler];
}
```

Comment: Is the jquery library already supported within WKWebView? or did you have to import that as well?

Comment: This ajaxHandler is not working for me. I keep getting errors saying unknown variable $. Any ideas?

Comment: @iOSAddicted You're probably not importing jQuery in the response of the original request ($ is a JQuery variable)

Comment: @CharltonProvatas, given halil_g's answer looks like it's not supported by WKWebView and needs to be imported in the response web content.

Answer (score 25):

@Benzi Heler answer is great, but it uses jQuery which seems like is not working in `WKWebView` anymore, so I have found solution without using jQuery.

Here is ViewController implementation that lets you be notified every AJAX request is completed in `WKWebView`:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    private var wkWebView: WKWebView!
    private let handler = "handler"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: getScript(), injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        config.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: handler)

        wkWebView = WKWebView(frame:  view.bounds, configuration: config)
        view.addSubview(wkWebView)

        if let url = URL(string: "YOUR AJAX WEBSITE") {
            wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        } else {
            print("Wrong URL!")
        }
    }

    private func getScript() -> String {
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "script", ofType: "js") {
            do {
                return try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        } else {
            print("script.js not found!")
        }
        return ""
    }
}

extension WebViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if let dict = message.body as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, let status = dict["status"] as? Int, let responseUrl = dict["responseURL"] as? String {
            print(status)
            print(responseUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty standard implementation. There is a `WKWebView` created programmatically. There is injected script that is loaded from `script.js` file.

And the most important part is `script.js` file:

```
var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    this.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var message = {"status" : this.status, "responseURL" : this.responseURL}
        webkit.messageHandlers.handler.postMessage(message);
    });
    open.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

`userContentController` delegate method will be called every time there is AJAX request loaded. I'm passing there `status` and `responseURL`, because this was what I needed in my case, but you can also get more informations about request. Here is the list of all properties and methods available:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

My solution is inspired by this answer written by @John Culviner:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27363569/3448282

Comment: is it possible to inject the configuration after WKWebView is loaded?

Comment: No - you can only set a WKWebView's configuration in its `init` method

Comment: It's not working, it actually messes with the navigation flow.

Comment: @user3448282 I need to observe captcha change in Ajax. On didLoad I'm using "var c = document.createElement('canvas'); var ctx = c.getContext('2d'); const list = document.getElementsByTagName(\"img\"); ctx.drawImage(list[1], 100, 40); var value = c.toDataURL(); value.split(',')[1];". Can I do this in script.js If then now to add it in script.js ?

Comment: Its great. I can catch json of network calls

Answer (score 5):

If you have control of the content inside the `WkWebView` you can send messages to your native app using `window.webkit.messageHandlers` whenever you make an ajax request, which will be received as a [`WKScriptMessage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKScriptMessage/) that can be processed by whatever you've designated as your [`WKScriptMessageHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKScriptMessageHandler_Ref/).  The messages can contain whatever information you wish, and will be automatically converted into native objects/values in your Objective-C or Swift code.

If you don't have control over the content you can still do this by injecting your own JavaScript via a [`WKUserScript`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKUserScript_Ref/) to track ajax requests and send back messages using the method stated above.

Comment: I don't have control of the content inside the WKWebview. Still will I be able to get the ajax request?

Comment: @BenziHeler, You mentioned that u don't have the control of the content inside the WKWebview but you are saying you have solved it the way Justin Michael suggested.... Can you please explain can it be possible it you don't have the control of the webview content?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to respond to requests from the WKWebView. It works similar to UIWebView.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView2 decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    
    if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated) {
     
        NSString *url = [navigationAction.request.URL absoluteString];
        
       // Handle URL request internally

    }

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow); // Will continue processing request

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel); // Cancels request
}
```