# How to monitor http requests from WKWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, httprequest, wkwebview

So, it is pretty clear question I think. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766676/how-can-i-monitor-requests-on-wkwebview) is about monitoring ajax requests. I tried it but didn't work as I wanted.

How can I call a function in my native iOS Obj-C application every time a request is sent, received and the browsing link is changed in WKWebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way.

You can create a new class (let's call it `MyURLProtocol`) which has [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlprotocol) as subclass. Then add this function to  `MyURLProtocol`:

```
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"URL = %@", request.URL.absoluteString);
    return NO;
}
```

This function will be called each time your webview makes a request. And then you need to register this protocol with the loading system. In your `Appdelegate.m` file include your class and add/replace `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function with this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyURLProtocol class]];
    return YES;
}
```

All set. Now you can edit `canInitWithRequest` function and do what you want with the request.

Comment: doesn't seem to work in Swift iOS 13 when there are multiple webviews in the app :/