# Get callback when UIWebView finishes loading Ajax

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Is it possible to get notified when Ajax has finished loading in UIWebView? In Android I was able to do it like this:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private void setUpWebView() {
    webview = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "HtmlViewer");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new LoginWebView());
    webview.loadUrl("EXAMPLE URL");
}

private class LoginWebView extends WebViewClient {
    @SuppressLint({"JavascriptInterface"})
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
            "\n" + "    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){" +
            "\n" + "        var responseCode = JSON.parse(request.responseText).result.responseCode;" +
            "\n" + "        window.HtmlViewer.ajaxResponse(settings.url, responseCode);" +
            "\n" + "    });" +
            "\n" + "})();";);
    }
}

private class JavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void ajaxResponse(String url, String responseCode) {
        // Gets notified when Ajax finished loading
    }
}
```

Now every time Ajax has finished loading, my `ajaxResponse` method is being called. Is it possible to achieve that also in UIWebView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found solution to this problem. There are many solution out there, but all of them uses jQuery which seems not working in `WKWebView`. Here is my solution in raw `JavaScript`.

Here is ViewController implementation that lets you be notified every AJAX request is completed in `WKWebView`:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    private var wkWebView: WKWebView!
    private let handler = "handler"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: getScript(), injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        config.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: handler)

        wkWebView = WKWebView(frame:  view.bounds, configuration: config)
        view.addSubview(wkWebView)

        if let url = URL(string: "YOUR AJAX WEBSITE") {
            wkWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        } else {
            print("Wrong URL!")
        }
    }

    private func getScript() -> String {
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "script", ofType: "js") {
            do {
                return try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        } else {
            print("script.js not found!")
        }
        return ""
    }
}

extension WebViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if let dict = message.body as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, let status = dict["status"] as? Int, let responseUrl = dict["responseURL"] as? String {
            print(status)
            print(responseUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty standard implementation. There is a `WKWebView` created programmatically. There is injected script that is loaded from `script.js` file.

And the most important part is `script.js` file:

```
var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    this.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var message = {"status" : this.status, "responseURL" : this.responseURL}
        webkit.messageHandlers.handler.postMessage(message);
    });
    open.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

`userContentController` delegate method will be called every time there is AJAX request loaded. I'm passing there `status` and `responseURL`, because this was what I needed in my case, but you can also get more informations about request. Here is the list of all properties and methods available:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

My solution is inspired by this answer written by @John Culviner:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27363569/3448282

Answer (score 0):

You can use `evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:`

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("yourJSfuncsToRunAJAX") { response, error in
    //if error didn't occure do sth after js function finished
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is that I need to use `UIWebView` which doesn't let to use `evaluateJavaScript` function with callback. I think I could try using `WKWebView` (it has bad cookie management system, that's why I need to use `UIWebView`).  The problem is I don't know how should JS script look like in iOS version. On Android I'm calling `window.HtmlViewer.ajaxResponse(settings.url, responseCode);` that let's me deliver callback information to my function. How to achieve this on iOS?

Comment: @user3448282 Apple recommend to use WKWebView, so give it a try ;)

JS is pretty similiar on every browser so if it works on chromium-based browser it should work on safari base too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately UIWebView is deprecated from iOS 8, so you should switch to WKWebView.
From [apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview): "In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView."

To get notified if ajax finished you can use the accepted response from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766676/how-can-i-monitor-requests-on-wkwebview). I used the same principle for bridging between javascript and swift.

Hope it helps.