# How to correctly listen to navigation changes on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I noticed that the `[UIWebViewDelegate webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:]` is only called with traditional `<a href="...">` links and not single page web app JavaScript navigations.

For example, if I go to m.facebook.com in a `UIWebView` and start tapping on the top nav (see screenshot below) it never triggers that delegate method.

The reason I want a method to hook into is because I want to add back and forward buttons above the UIWebView but I need to know when to enable/disable those buttons. Is there some other delegate method I should use to correctly listen to navigation changes?

Update: I should also note that mobile Safari correctly updates the back/forward button state on the Facebook mobile site, so I'd hope Apple exposes a way for developers to do this as well.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `[UIWebView canGoBack]`? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview/1617931-cangoback

Comment: @SergGr that doesn't help me because I need some hook when there are navigation changes to know when to call canGoBack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like this is simply not supported by UIWebViewDelegate, nor WKNavigationDelegate (which I just tested with facebook).  There are some options listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23055471/467209):

> 1. javascript injection to capture the page changes (read up on history.pushState).
> 2. KVO to watch for changes to the webview (like the scrollview resizing)
> 3. watching for the title change, as above.
> 4. checking for updates every time the user taps the view.

*Update*

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5738723/467209) on facebook, which involves injecting javascript to catch XMLHTTPRequests during each new page load.  It *sort of* does what you're asking for, but is a bit of a hack.  Some of the facebook tabs don't work properly with a very simple implementation, but you may be able to work around the issues.